# Why this warning is showed for using marquee tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

WARNING in src\Pages\Home\Banner\Banner.js
Line 17:29:  Do not use  elements as they can create visual accessibility issues and are deprecated  jsx-a11y/no-distracting-elements

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Answer (score 0):

This feature of marquee tag in html is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes.

Instead of using it. You can use [React Fast Marquee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fast-marquee)
to replace and custom default tag marquee in html.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).